# Insert a String between Strings

Tags: java

I have a `String [] Names` which contain couple of values like this one

```
[Alex Jones, Robert Flip, Farabi Fahim]
```

Now, my question is

1) Now, I would like to replace the last `","` with `&` before the last Character[Here it is Farabi Fahim]. How do i do that ?

output will be like

```
[Alex Jones, Robert Flip & Farabi Fahim]
```

2)What will be the Fastest, efficient and recommended way to do that ?

Comment: You mean last element?

Comment: do you want [Alex, Robert, &Farabi] or [Alex, Robert, &, Farabi] as output?

Comment: find last ,
insert &
add the rest - I think this is the fastest way

Comment: You forgot the `,` in the output?

Comment: Ah, the smell of homework.

Comment: No love for the Oxford comma?

Comment: I would just use `Arrays.toString()`, then replace the last instance of the comma with an ampersand. Do this if you just need the String output as listed and don't have to utilize the array again.

Comment: You're sure that you have a `String[]` here? To me this would make more sense if you have a `char[]` which you want to manipulate...

Comment: It's a bit unclear. Do you mean you have something like `String[] names = {"Alex Jones, Robert Flip, Farabi Fahim", "John, Paul, George, Ringo", "Billy, James, D'arcy, Jimmy"}` or something like `String[] names = {"Alex Jones", "Robert Flip", "Farabi Fahim"}`?

Comment: Are you trying to combine all the `String`s in the array into one `String`, or change multiple `String`s in an array so that each of them has the last comma replaced by an ampersand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
String[] arr = new String[] {"Alex Jones", "Robert Flip", "Farabi Fahim"};
StringBuilder sbd = new StringBuilder("[");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sbd.append(arr[i]);
    if (i < arr.length - 2)
        sbd.append(", ");
    else if (i < arr.length - 1)
        sbd.append(" & ");
}
sbd.append(']');
System.out.printf("%s%n", sbd);
```

#### Alternative one-liner solution:

```
String output = Arrays.toString(arr).replaceAll(", (?=[^,]*$)", " & ")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[Alex Jones, Robert Flip & Farabi Fahim]
```

Comment: That is inefficient and unnecessarily long-winded. You should use System.arrayCopy() instead. 3 lines. That solution also produces a String and not the requested String array.

Comment: @AlvinThompson: Did you run any benchmark to prove that it is indeed `inefficient`?

Comment: As opposed to a native array copy call built into the JVM specifically for this purpose? Are you serious? However, I think I may have misinterpreted the question. If so and he does want a String, your solution is fine.

Comment: Too many Java programmers are afraid the crap they write could be inefficient.

Comment: @Ingo - the more lines of code you write, the greater the chance of a bug. Even assuming the asker wants a String, this solution is 10 lines of code as opposed to 4. It's also harder to follow and maintain.

Comment: @AlvinThompson - If you pay attention to what the OP is asking for, it's fairly clear that the are asking for a comma separated string of their array (the default product of calling `toString`). In that respect, this is quite correct. Obviously, I prefer a method with a little less logic...but mine is still quite similar.

Comment: Not to mention it is indeed much slower and less efficient with memory than System.arrayCopy().

Comment: Does no one here know about the basic libraries built into java? After you get the array, use `Arrays.toString()` on it. 4 lines and no loops.

Comment: @anubhava - you get exactly what he asked for.

Comment: @anubhava - It's in my answer. Tested and works fine. 4 lines, far more readable, far more maintainable, and far more efficient.

Comment: Looking back, my tone in my original comment was much less diplomatic than I intended, which I imagine is causing much of the animosity. For that I apologize.

Comment: @AlvinThompson: np at all, just fyi I have provided an one-liner answer as well above.

Answer (score 1):

You're converting an array of strings to a single string in this case (it looks like the output of your first statement was just using the `toString` method. The easiest way is a `for` loop:

```
String str = arr[0];
for (int i = 1; i < (arr.length - 1); i++) {
    str += (", " + arr[i]);
}
str += (" & " + arr[arr.length - 1]);
```

Or, if you wanted to truly be more efficient, you could use the `StringBuilder` class to build the string:

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(arr[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < (arr.length - 1); i++) {
    strBuilder.append(", ");
    strBuilder.append(arr[i]);
}
strBuilder.append(" & ");
strBuilder.append(arr[arr.length - 1]);
String str = strBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: Might be worth using a `StringBuilder` ?

Comment: I'm not sure that's what OP is doing.

Comment: @Chris - If this were production code, it definitely would be. Considering the OP isn't sure how to write the loop to build the string, I'd hold off on using `StringBuilder` for now.

Comment: I'll post it in another answer, just for future readers. :)

Comment: @Chris - Added it anyway (but left the original as well).

Comment: Fair enough. Might as well delete my answer then! :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
String[] s1 = new String[] {"Alex Jones", "Robert Flip", "Farabi Fahim"};
```

Do this:

```
String[] s2 = new String[] {s1[0], s1[1] + " & " + s1[2]};
```

More generically (omitting sanity checks):

```
String[] s2 = new String[s1.length - 1];
System.arraycopy(s1, 0, s2, 0, s2.length);
s2[s2.length - 1] += " & " + s1[s1.length - 1];
```

If you want the output as a String instead of a String array, add this line:

```
String out = Arrays.toString(s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Next time post some of your own code.

```
// create new array that is one element shorter, i.e. [Alex,Robert]
String[] newnames = Array.copyOf(names, names.length-1);
// attach the formerly last element to the new last element
newnames[newnames.length-1] = newnames[newnames.length-1] + "&" + names[names.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a quick loop for printing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        if(i == names.length - 2)
            System.out.print(names[i] + " & ");
        else if(i < names.length - 1)
            System.out.print(names[i] + ", ");
        else
            System.out.print(names[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public String addAnd(String[] s)
{
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length - 2; i++)
    {
        result += s[i] + ", "
    }
    result += s[s.length - 2];
    result += (" & " + s[s.length - 1]);
    return result;
}
```

This should do the trick.